# Remove Null as output in the array laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

I want response like wherever "null" for the material is there remove that whole array index and give output.
For the following response code remove null values for the material:

```
{
    [0]=> array(3) { 
        ["iot"]=> int(1172141637653120) 
        ["datetime"]=> string(19) "2017-05-11 11:32:39" 
        ["material"]=> NULL 
    }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        ["iot"]=> int(8567763953469695) 
        ["datetime"]=> string(19) "2017-05-11 11:32:39" 
        ["material"]=> string(13) "2134803942910" 
    }
}
```

Just like where ever the material code is NULL. I want remove that whole index for that i tried below method but it's not coming:

```
      $array= array_map('array_filter', $array);
```

I need output like below:

```
 [1]=> array(3) {
    ["iot"]=> int(8567763953469695) 
    ["datetime"]=> string(19) "2017-05-11 11:32:39" 
    ["material"]=> string(13) "2134803942910" 
}
```

Please any help and thanks in advance?

Comment: Where ever the material code is NULL, that particular index should be removed and give output, for above one remove [0]=>array(3) and give output only [1]=>array(3).

Comment: see my answer to explain how :)